Paginated RTK Query with multiple parameters
I'm utilizing RTK Query for managing API requests in my React application, particularly for pagination. In my component, I have implemented pagination using useGetPopularItemsQuery from RTK Query. However, I'm encountering a problem with automatic request triggering when certain parameters change.
Here's a simplified version of my component:
const PopularItemsListing = ({ limitedSet, categoriesSet }: Props) => {
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [tryAgain, setTryAgain] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [noMoreItems, setNoMoreItems] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const { ref, inView } = useInView();
  const [allPopularItems, setAllPopularItems] = useState<ItemType[]>([]);
  const [shouldSkip, setShouldSkip] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const { data, error, isLoading } = useGetPopularItemsQuery(
    {
      page: currentPage,
      limit: 8,
      limited: limitedSet,
      tags: categoriesSet.join(","),
    },
    { retry: tryAgain, skip: shouldSkip }
  );

  // Other rendering logic and event handlers...
};

The issue arises when either categoriesSet or limitedSet changes, I have to reset the page to 1 and this triggering multiple requests due to RTK Query's behavior (due to changing the other variables and the page counter). I want to ensure that if either of these parameters changes, the pagination resets to page 1 before making a new request.
But if the user is just scrolling and only the page number is changing, I want to make a request with the updated page number.

How can I achieve this behavior effectively with RTK Query?
Hoping to find some help.
